# Timer command not functioning

Tags: discord

So basically I made a timer command using ms.js, and when i use the command /timer 5s, it responds with the timer has ended directly after without actually waiting the 5 seconds, any help?

```
        case 'timer':
            let time = ms(args[1])
            setTimeout(() => {
                message.channel.send('Your timer has now ended.')
                }, ms(time));
        break;
```

Comment: check the value of `time` first,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all check the value of `time` variable. if that is ok then modify your code like below. and be careful that the `setTimeout` use millisecond as time parameter

```
case 'timer':
            let time = ms(args[1])
            setTimeout(() => {
                message.channel.send('Your timer has now ended.')
                },time);
        break;
```